# Different specification of WPF grid row sizes of the same user control depending of situation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, rowdefinition

I have done reusable user control which is used few times in my project.

Usually the second row of the main grid needs to be 7 times bigger than first one, but in a particular situation it needs to be just 5 times bigger.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

I tried to set it through XAML:

```
<helperControls:AttachmentsGridControl x:Name="projectAttachmentsControl" ... HeightOfSecondRow="5" />
```

and in .cs part:

```
public int HeightOfSecondRow { get; set; }
public AttachmentsGridControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(HeightOfSecondRow > 0)
        this.mainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(HeightOfSecondRow, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

But the value is not passed while constructors of controls are called. The value needs to be passed on a time when constructor is called, so I can specify how much the height of the second row needs to be and render it properly.

Comment: What is the condition in which the row needs to be 5 times bigger instead of 7 times?

Comment: Probably I wrongly started the project at the beginning. I set 40 rows and 40 columns of the main grid. Within this I have many controls, including my new own user controls, for some instances I have place through 6 rows and for some 8 rows. Just temporary design issue. Until I would learn how to do it well and refactor all to be scalable and 4k support I would like to fix this issue, so it looks ok, no matter if the same user control is through 6 or 8 rows of my main window grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the `HeightOfSecondRow` in the constructor, make it a dependency property of type `GridLength` with a default value of `7*`. The coerce value callback will ensure that a value that is set in XAML or bound with a binding will be positive, otherwise it will be replaced with the default value.

```
public partial class AttachmentsGridControl : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightOfSecondRowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(HeightOfSecondRow), typeof(GridLength), typeof(AttachmentsGridControl),
      new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(7, GridUnitType.Star), null, OnCoerceValue));

   public GridLength HeightOfSecondRow
   {
      get => (GridLength)GetValue(HeightOfSecondRowProperty);
      set => SetValue(HeightOfSecondRowProperty, value);
   }

   public AttachmentsGridControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private static object OnCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object value)
   {
      var gridLength = (GridLength)value;
      return gridLength.Value > 0.0 ? gridLength : HeightOfSecondRowProperty.GetMetadata(d).DefaultValue;
   }
}
```

Adapt the binding of `Height` to use the `HeightOfSecondRow` property of your `AttachmentsGridControl`.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="{Binding HeightOfSecondRow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AttachmentsGridControl}}}"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <!-- ...your content. -->
</Grid>
```

Then you can set the `HeightOfSecondRow` as before. If you do not set it, the default value will be used.

```
<local:AttachmentsGridControl x:Name="projectAttachmentsControl" HeightOfSecondRow="20*"/>
```

Comment: I was thinking that I would not need to use Dependency Property just for this, but I am getting used to it, as recently I have often cases for this.
Anyway thank you very much, ofcourse answer accepted and giving plus. Best Regards and thank you Sir.

Comment: Just for information:
I had to make your dependency property static, because otherway I was getting the error that it is already registered. But, because I changed it into static, I got to hardcoded the default value in the last line of OnCoerceValue method.
I wrote it just for information (maybe I missed something, or maybe you got an interesting information), I am very thankful for your help :)

Comment: @ninidow359 Thank you and sorry, of course dependency properties must be `static`, corrected.